# ¿Qué signfica y de dónde viene la expresión "romperse los cascos"?

Tags: modismos, etimología

Oigo de vez en cuando la expresión "romperse los cascos" para referirse a "pensar mucho algo". En general se usa para denominar algo que no deberías hacer:

> No te rompas los cascos: tu novia te dejó y ya está

o bien

> Estuve toda la noche rompiéndome los cascos con ese problema de
>   matemáticas. ¡Al final resultó ser una tontería!

He estado buscando y no acabo de encontrar referencias válidas al origen de esta expresión. ¿Alguien lo sabe?

Comment: En Peru se usa «romperse el coco».

Comment: Estoy pensando que lo mismo "cascos" se refiere a las uñas de los caballos: si se rompe, querrá decir que vamos muy rápidos porque tenemos afán. Por contra, no romperse los cascos querrá decir ir tranquilo.

Comment: Nunca he oído romperse los cascos. Las alternativas más habituales que he oído en España son "romperse el coco" para referirse a pensar mucho en algo y "romperse los cuernos" para referirse a situaciones que suponen un gran esfuerzo.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Casco](http://lema.rae.es/drae2001/srv/search?id=8XxD0dl1BDXX2uJAgcGw) puede significar, en lenguaje coloquial, "cabeza". Y la alusión se extiende, más allá de lo físico-anatómico, a lo mental. “Romperse los cascos” significa pues -igual que "romperse la cabeza"- hacer un esfuerzo mental.

Answer (score 2):

> No te rompas los cascos y cierra esta publicación.

En Perú se "usa romperse el coco", cuando se está en el proceso de estudiar algo.

En Costa Rica se usa "romperse la jupa", cuando estás pensando.

Comment: En España se usa "comerse el coco", "comerse la cabeza" o "comerse la olla". Todas referidas a la cabeza, que es donde pensamos. Entiendo que "romperse los cascos" es lo mismo que "romperse el coco" o "comerse el coco", pero con "cascos" haciendo mención a la cabeza, al fin y al cabo el casco se lo pone uno ahi